# Selecting last day of week in datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, momentjs, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I'm using `moment.js` to try to select the last day of the week that is selected in the `datetimepicker` but it returns a continuous loop for every last day of every week. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong please could someone help me.

This is the JS that I have tried.

**JS**

```
$(datePick).on('change.datetimepicker', () => {
    var datetimePicker = $("#datetimepicker1").val();
    lastDate = moment(datetimePicker, "YYYY-MM-DD").day(7).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    $(datePick).val(lastDate);
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: the variable `datePick` -- where is it defined? That's really the places I can see you getting a loop from.

Comment: It's outside the function as a global variable

Comment: And what value does it have?

Comment: var datePick = $("#datetimepicker1");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you don't select the last day of the week, but the Sunday of the next week by using `moment(...).day(7)`. After that you set the value, which will trigger the on change function again, setting the value to the Sunday a week later. And so on... (continuous loop)

So you need to change `moment(...).day(7)` to `moment(...).day(6)`, which will select the Saturday of the current week. In the second try, it will not change the value again and the loop stops.

If you want to select the next Sunday as the end of the week instead of Saturday, I suggest doing something like

```
$(datePick).on('change.datetimepicker', () => {
    var datetimePicker = $("#datetimepicker1").val();
    if (moment(datetimePicker.day() !== 0) {
        lastDate = moment(datetimePicker, "YYYY-MM-DD").day(7).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
        $(datePick).val(lastDate);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! :) It triggered the event twice would that be because of the on change? I need it to be sunday as the last day of the week because of where I stay. But thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it worked. Yes, the on change triggered the second execution, but the added if statement prevents further calls. And if you pick a Sunday, it will only trigger it once.